# Spring WebClient Client Credentials grant type 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring `WebClient` to make a call to my resource server using `client_credentials` grant_type

Am using `'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.10.RELEASE'`

and these are all the dependencies

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

Am Making a call to my `resource-server` using the below code and the call is **absolutely successful**

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("my-custom-client")
    WebClient clientForMyResourceServer;

    @GetMapping("/consume")
    public String consumeResourceServer () {
        String response = "Reply from Resource Server is  : ";

        String responseFromResourceServer = clientForMyResourceServer
                .get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hello/ping")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

        return response + responseFromResourceServer;
    }
```

But what happens, this client is getting the `Bearer-Token` from the OAuth-server only during the time of boot-up and it doesn't fetch any fresh `Bearer-Token` after the one that it already has is expired.

The `Bearer-Token` that i get will be active only for `5 minutes` and will expire from the 6th minute. So from the 6th minute i cannot make any call to my `resource-server` with this `WebClient` and get `401 Unauthorized`. It works normal again after i restart my `consumer-application`

please help

Comment: Could you provide `WebClient` configuration?

Comment: Why don't you use OAuth2RestTemplate instead of WebClient?